# Switch statements: do you need the last break? (Javascript mainly)

Tags: javascript, performance, switch-statement

When using a `switch()` statement, you add `break;` in between separate `case:` declarations.  But what about the **last** one?

Normally I just leave it off, but I'm wondering if this has some performance implication I'm not thinking about?

I've been wondering about this for a while and don't see it asked elsewhere on Stack-O, but sorry if I missed it.

I'm mainly asking this question regarding Javascript, although I'm guessing the answer will apply to all `switch()` statements.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was a performance hit. Personally I always put it in in case in the future I need to move the cases around. Plus I'm a bit anal like that...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Performance should not be a consideration at all.  Even if some language or implementation has a performance difference that's measurable in a micro-benchmark, it would never cause a real-world performance issue.

I think the most important issue is consistency and maintainability.  If you leave off the last `break` and then another developer adds another case statement without realizing you left off the `break`, the behavior would change.  It's really the second developer's fault for not noticing the `break` is missing, but it could have been avoided by being consistent and having the `break` on all `case` clauses.

Answer (score 4):

It's completely unnecessary from a performance stand-point, but a very good habit to maintain, since you might forget to add the break when you introduce more cases. Obviously this doesn't apply to `default`.

Comment: *"Obviously this doesn't apply to default."* Sure it does, `default` doesn't have to be the last case (although that's where *I* always put it).