# Why do you need to put break after the last label of a switch statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Surely the compiler knows that it's the last label of the `switch` statement?

Comment: It is to help you the programmer, not the compiler. what if you add another statement after that and forget the break?

Comment: @Byron: That would be a compile error in C#, no? So you would notice.

Comment: @Thilo - Just because it is a compile error doesn't mean the compiler needs it. Compile time errors are much easier and cheaper to correct than runtime ones. This is why Microsoft included this in the language spec. See c/c++.

Comment: @Byron: That is what I meant. The compile error and the requirement to have the break are there to help the programmer (as opposed to C/C++ where the mistake you mentioned can easily happen). I think we are on the same page. (+1 for the C# language designers for this by the way, I wish the Java guys had had the same idea. This is a good case for breaking backwards compatibility with C syntax)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch statements: do you need the last break? (Javascript mainly)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729813/switch-statements-do-you-need-the-last-break-javascript-mainly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a break after your switch's final case statement is good [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).  If, perhaps in the future, another case statement is added below, it removes the risk of the program's flow *falling through* from the case above.

Comment: MS says default is always evaluated last: "The default case can appear in any order in the switch statement. Regardless of its order in the source code, it's always evaluated last, after all case labels have been evaluated." So your reasoning is not correct.

Answer (score 7):

It's because in C++ this is what happens:

```
switch(a)
{
     case 1:
        // do stuff

     case 2:
        // do other stuff
}
```

If `a` is 1, then - according to C++ rules - both "do stuff" *and* "do other stuff" would happen. So that C++ programmers coming to C# do not get tripped up (and to make code clearer all 'round), C# requires that you explicitly specify whether you want to `break` or fall through to a different label.

Now, as for why you need the `break` on the *last* block, that's a simple matter of consistency. It also make re factoring easier: if you move the cases around, you don't suddenly end up with errors because of a missing `break` statement. Also, what happens when you want to add another label, etc, etc.

Comment: I'm talking about after the last label. There are no more labels to fall through to, so there is no need for the break statement.

Answer (score 3):

In [C# switch statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664749(VS.71).aspx)  you must explicitly state to break or goto another case or goto default.

In C and C++, switch statements have fall through labels without a break.  Having the user explicitly say what they want to do is important in C# to avoid bugs.  A lot of users come to C# from C++ for example.

---

About the last case statement in particular that you're asking about.  I can think of 3 good reasons.

1. It's important to keep things consistent in any language.
2. What if you append another case after it later on, what should be done with default?
3. Why should break be the default? Why not goto? There is ambiguity here.

Comment: It's a C# question. But regardless, why would the compiler need to break after the last label?

Comment: It doesn't NEED it, but the language REQUIRES it.

Answer (score 3):

Consistency. Same reason as being able to have a comma after the last enum definition or the last assignment in an object instantiation statement with  braces. And the last case might not always be the last case.

It also makes it so there are fewer special cases.

And if that's the case, then it is easier to learn, write, or read. Although that adds to the consistency thing.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

> You cannot "fall through" any switch section, including the last one.

Fall through can be avoided by any of the following: break, goto, or return.

Comment: lol. I was just referring to what the website said, not what's smart.

Answer (score 2):

Actually **There is one case when you don't have to put break**

Consider this code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void DoStuff()
    {
    }

    public static void DoAnotherStuff()
    {
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        switch(1)
        {
            case 1: DoStuff(); break;
            default: DoAnotherStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Using C# 4.0 compiler it only gives you a nice CS0162: Unreachable code warning

It appears that since switch has a constant expression the compiler already knows wich path it's going to execute, then just ignores the dafault label.

The cool thing is that if you change switch(1) to switch(2) it no longer compiles because the default label lacks its break.

**Edit:** From the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

> The requirement in C# is that the end of every switch section, including the final one, is unreachable. Although this requirement usually is met by using a jump statement, the following case also is valid, because the end of the statement list cannot be reached.

```
case 4:
    while (true)
        Console.WriteLine("Endless looping. . . .");
```

That explains why the default does not need a break. In fact any unreacheable label doesn't need a break nor return nor goto

Comment: "That explains why the default does not need a break. In fact any unreacheable label doesn't need a break nor return nor goto" But it doesn´t explain, why we need a break on *reachable* code. Cool post anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `switch`, to `break` is not the only option. You also have the option of going to another case, going to the default case, going to another label, or returning. It is also possible to have multiple cases that have a single implementation body. Since there are up to five options plus the ability to have multiple cases for one implementation, the compiler is not able to simply put in the "correct" answer.

You have to choose what you intend to do. It ensures the compiler does the right thing, makes your code clearer, and makes it more difficult to do dumb-programmer-things, like add another case after the "last one", and forget to put in a break/goto/return.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2009/08/13/four-switch-oddities/) by Eric Lippert (Case 2), it allows you to be able to arbitrarily re-order your switch sections without accidentally introducing a breaking change:

> It [the compiler] requires that every switch section,
> including the last one, have an
> unreachable end point. The purpose of
> this rule, and of the no-fall-through
> rule in general, is that we want you
> to be able to arbitrarily re-order
> your switch sections without
> accidentally introducing a breaking
> change.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use default:, but consider case null too. case null: does need a break;

case null:
iEvaluatedToNothing();
break;

If you want to "waterfall" down you can do something like this;

```
switch (deliverMail)
{
    case null:
    case "":
    case "Address0":
        deliverMail0();
        goto case "1";
    case "1":
        deliverMail1();
        break;
}
```

You can use this with breaks as needed, but one is required on the last evaluation.