# Why can I declare a variable after a label in GCC, but not Clang?

Tags: c, gcc, label, clang

I found some code that compiles under gcc but not under clang:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int test = 0;

    if (test == 0) {
        goto print_five;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

 print_five:
    int five = 6;

    printf("value of five: %d\n", five);
    return 0;
}
```

if I declare the variable `five` to the top of the function (under `test`),
then the program compiles under both compilers.

After reading questions [1] and [2], I thought maybe it had to do with
potentially skipping a variable declaration, similar to needing to create scope in case statements. The following examples compile in both compilers as well.

```
print_five:
    printf("value of five: ");
    int five = 6;
    printf("%d\n", five);
    
    return 0;
```

```
print_five: ;
    int five = 6;     
    printf("value of five: %d\n", five);
    return 0;
```

however, it seems that this isn't the case, and has to do with having an expression directly after a label (also explained in question [3]).
Why would this example compile with GCC but not with Clang? Wouldn't this indicate a bug within one or the other?

1. [Overkilling "crosses initialization of variable" error in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100504/overkilling-crosses-initialization-of-variable-error-in-c)
2. [In C why do you need a statement after a goto label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730893/in-c-why-do-you-need-a-statement-after-a-goto-label)
3. [Variable declaration after goto Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384388/variable-declaration-after-goto-label)

Comment: The next release of clang will compile it in C23 mode. If you use C18 mode, it'll say _"error: label followed by a declaration is a C23 extension"_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before C99, all variable declarations had to be at the top of a scope block, since a declaration is not a statement:

```
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    puts("hi");
    a = 5;
    puts("ok");
}
```

Since C99 you can declare variables in the middle of a function. This means there wouldn't have really been a reason to write a label before a declaration in the past, and apparently labels never got changed to be allowed to be placed before a declaration (until C23, more below). There are some simple fixes:

```
    // ...
    int five;
SetFive:
    five = 5;
    // ...
```

or:

```
    // ...
SetFive:
    {}
    int five = 5;
    // ...
```

GCC seems to be non-compliant, that is, compiling code it "shouldn't." Setting GCC to use `-std=c99` even permits this, however using the `-pedantic` flag will give a warning.

Clang however seems to be standard compliant in this aspect and will not compile it (even with `-std=c2x`).

This actually is a feature in C23, which should be released next year. I would recommend you use one of the work-a-rounds above until C23 is officially released.

Clang and GCC, for better or for worse, both like to enable their own extensions by default which can make code compile in one, but not the other.

Answer (score 3):

A *declaration* and a *statement* are two separate things in the C grammar, and different rules apply to them.

As an example, this is valid:

```
if (x==0) y=1;
```

But this is not:

```
if (x==0) int z;
```

When it comes to labels, in C17 and earlier a label may only be followed by a statement, not a declaration.

In C23 the grammar changes so that a label is implicitly followed by a null statement when it is part of a compound statement (i.e. contained within `{}`), so in that version of the standard it is allowed to have a label immediately proceeded by a declaration.

In other words, in C23 this:

```
my_label:
  int i;
```

Is treated as this:

```
my_label:
  ;
  int i;
```

GCC apparently allows this new syntax as an extension even when not in C23 mode, while clang does not have this extension.